# How to (quickly) switch to dark mode in Ubuntu with GNOME and to make it fully dark?

Tags: themes, gtk, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a way to (quickly) turn on a dark mode in Ubuntu with GNOME, e.g. 18.04 and higher? And how is possible to have a dark mode of the different apps?
I agree with this article: [Ubuntu Needs to Make it Easier to Enable Dark Mode (OMG! Ubuntu)](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/01/changing-theme-in-ubuntu-should-be-easier)

There are some answers for Ubuntu with Unity but they are not helpful for Ubuntu with GNOME:
[How can you enable GTK3 themes' dark theme mode when using Unity 7? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806200/how-can-you-enable-gtk3-themes-dark-theme-mode-when-using-unity-7)
[Is there any fast switch between light mode and dark mode (light/dark theme) in 16.04? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/773236/is-there-any-fast-switch-between-light-mode-and-dark-mode-light-dark-theme-in)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **easy and quick** **toggling** from Dark to Light **theme** and vice versa install this GNOME extension:

- [Night Theme Switcher (GNOME Shell Extension)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2236/night-theme-switcher/), it has a lot of settings options incl. automated switch based on time.
- [Ubuntu Appearance (GNOME Shell Extension)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4335/ubuntu-appearance-gnome-40/) integrates Light, Dark, Standard option into system tray menu. For pictures and more info including installation, see [UbuntuHandbook article](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/toggle-dark-light-mode-ubuntu-extension/).

Invert the **color of individual windows** only (Default shortcut is Super+I): use the [Globe Extension Invert Window Color](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1041/invert-window-color/).
[Thank you Sam!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213047/how-to-quickly-switch-to-dark-mode-in-ubuntu-with-gnome-and-to-make-it-fully-dar/1213048?noredirect=1#comment2246005_1213048)

**Ubuntu 20.04**: You can now easily choose a **dark mode** within the **Settings**: `Appearance > Window colors > Dark`. There is no possibility to set a time to have an automatic switch based on time, though (without a GNOME extension, see above).

For a **Full Dark Mode** of the system (incl. System tray menu, top-bar calendar, notification popups, and desktop context menu) you need some more steps:

1. Install GNOME Tweaks and other tools if you don't have them, then reboot/restart. In a terminal:

```
    sudo apt install -y chrome-gnome-shell # Works with Firefox*, too.
    sudo apt install -y gnome-shell-extensions 
    sudo apt install -y gnome-tweak-tool
```

(*) [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) for GNOME Shell integration in Firefox.
2. Install *user themes* GNOME Shell extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/
3. Turn on *user themes* GNOME extension in GNOME Tweaks or in the GNOME extensions app.
4. Log out and back in to your session OR manually restart GNOME Shell (Alt + F2, type r, hit enter) for the theming extension to actually be activated.
5. Launch GNOME Tweaks and navigate to **Appearance** in the left pane, choose Yaru-dark as the Shell theme!
**More details and source:** [How to Enable Dark Gnome Shell Menus, Calendar in Ubuntu 20.04 | UbuntuHandbook]

GNOME 42 Now Supports **'Dark Wallpaper' Option**: When the (new standardised) dark mode setting is enabled a ‘dark’ version of the default wallpaper is applied. When light mode is enabled, a ‘light’ version of the wallpaper is applied.
For more information see [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/02/gnomr-42-dark-background-preference).

***In the future** this answer may be shorter, read [this GNOME blog article on Dark Style Preference](https://blogs.gnome.org/alexm/2021/10/04/dark-style-preference/).*

But the Dark Theme Toggle does not **make some of the apps fully dark** and you have to do **some further configuration**:

**LibreOffice**: (adapted from [Debugpoint.com](https://www.debugpoint.com/2020/01/how-to-enable-dark-mode-libreoffice/))

1. Open LibreOffice. Open any component – Writer, Calc etc.
2. From menu, click Tools -> Options.
3. Go to Application Colours, select document background as Black. You can also choose the Application background as *Black*.
   There may be more custom color settings you like to adapt. For example, [Remove the gray background from Table Of Contents](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/39434/how-to-remove-gray-background-from-table-of-contents-mac-user/): Modify the color setting in Text Document, ☑ Index and table shadings.
   (Or disable it: ☐ Index and table shadings.)
4. Some special formatting, e.g. links were not shown well on my computer, I chose a lighter colour for the unvisited and visited links.
5. If you would like to change to a dark icon theme, change it from "View" options on the left side for better visibility of the toolbar icons, e.g. choose "Breeze (dark) as icon style.

Update 2021/08: [With LO 7.2 you get a new LibreOffice **dark mode**](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.2) **colour scheme**. This is designed to compliment the dark theme enabled by your system. To enable it, head to:
Alternative Tools ▸ Options ▸ LibreOffice ▸ Application Colors theme 'LibreOffice Dark' and "apply" it.

There is a also a dark theme to install: [RaitaroH/LibreOffice-BreezeDark: Icons, color palette and color scheme for LibreOffice](https://github.com/RaitaroH/LibreOffice-BreezeDark)

**Firefox**:
Enable Dark **Mode** in Firefox, [see HowToGeek for details](https://www.howtogeek.com/359033/how-to-enable-dark-mode-in-firefox/).

- Click menu > Add-ons > Themes, choose Dark theme.

To view the **webpages** in dark colours, use an add-on. Two tested options:

1. [Dark Reader](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2236/night-theme-switcher/):

- Handy keyboard short-cut to toggle: Shift-Alt-D
- It promises that "it does not show ads and doesn't send user's data anywhere. It is [fully open-source](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader)."
- It may cause more CPU use, though.

2. [Dark Background and Light Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-background-light-text/)
   Before you install **disable** **similar** extensions.
   Handy keyboard short-cut to toggle: F9
3. [Midnight Lizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/midnight-lizard-quantum)
   Before you install **disable** **similar** extensions.
   Handy keyboard shortcuts to toggle extension:
     - on current website: Alt+Shift+L
     - globally: Alt+Shift+M

**PDF viewer** (e.g. Evince document viewer): See [Is there any pdf viewer with dark mode? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130512/is-there-any-pdf-viewer-with-dark-mode)
Go to the options on the top right corner (Sandwich menu).
Then select Night Mode or Inverted colours.

[**Wire messenger**](https://wire.com/) ([How to install Wire messenger on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu)):
Go to preferences, then Options, choose dark theme.

**Thunderbird**
With TB 78+ you can choose a dark **theme** (open add-on page and choose themes on the left side).
In Settings>General>Fonts&Colors>**Colors>Text and Background**: You can choose the colour of text and background (possibly uncheck "Use system colors").
Apart from that there are some dark theme add-ons with more tweaks (with TB 91+ some themes won't work anymore).

**[Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/themes.html#light)**:
The theme to use can be selected at Edit > Preferences > Interface
You can also [change the colour of the waves](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audio_tracks.html#colors) without selecting a theme.
And more sophisticated (source: [OMG!Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/05/audacity-dark-flat-theme)):

1. Download the [Audacity Clean Dark Theme pack](https://www.deviantart.com/podel1/art/Audacity-Clean-Dark-Theme-by-Podel-715604676)
2. Extract the .zip
3. Copy ImageCache.png from the named colour folder you want
4. Paste file into ~.audacity-data/Theme (if the directory doesn’t exist, create it)
5. Open Audacity > Preferences > Interface
6. Select ‘Custom’ theme option

**Calibre**: See [How do I get a dark theme/night mode in Calibre? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053497/how-do-i-get-a-dark-theme-night-mode-in-calibre)

**Qt Apps**: Make them follow System Light/Dark Style in Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/qgnomeplatform
sudo apt install qgnomeplatform-qt5
```

*NOTE: Ubuntu 23.04 and Ubuntu 23.10 users can directly run the last apt install command without adding PPA.*
(For details see [Ubuntu Handbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/10/qt-apps-follow-system-light-dark-style-ubuntu-22-04/))

Comment: Is there a way to install the user themes extension with `apt`?

Comment: @AaronFranke Thank you for your edit! Good question, I did not find a package for user themes with Synaptic Packages.

Comment: Once you install Gnome Tweaks, you can also install the Invert Window Color extension, to invert colors of **individual** windows.  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1041/invert-window-color/

Comment: I want this dark mode feature everywhere but firefox. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ajinzrathod Not sure which part of Firefox you don't want to be dark. I am not sure how to exclude a dark Firefox window decoration if you enable the Ubuntu system dark mode/theme. But maybe [Sam's comment regarding the invert window color extension can help you.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213047/how-to-quickly-switch-to-dark-mode-in-ubuntu-with-gnome-and-to-make-it-fully-dar/1213048?noredirect=1#comment2246005_1213048) If you don't want the pages or tabs dark, you don't install a "dark theme" add-on and don't turn on the dark theme of Firefox.

Answer (score 7):

If you are a terminal user, adding those lines to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` might come in handy, since you can change the theme with a single command (for **Ubuntu 20.04**):

```
function dark {
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-dark'
}

function light {
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru'
}
```

Now just type "light" or "dark" on your command line.

For the Cinnamon-Desktop (used by Linux Mint), the settings look a bit different:

```
function dark {
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Mint-Y-Dark'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Mint-Y-Dark'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Mint-Y-Dark'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name 'Mint-Y-Dark'
}

function light {
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Mint-Y'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Mint-Y'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Mint-Y'
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name 'Mint-Y'
}
```

Comment: The function does not work for me...